# Error in creating download link for files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, download

I am creating a function that displays a list of files from a specific folder and enable the users to download but i am having errors that states:

> "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code, {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: filename"}"

in the statement:

```
context.Response.WriteFile(context.Request.QueryString["files"]);
```

My code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp");
            rpt.DataSource = files;
            rpt.DataBind();
        }
    }
        protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
                {
                string file = e.Item.DataItem as string;
                HyperLink hyp = e.Item.FindControl("hyp") as HyperLink;
                hyp.Text = file;
                hyp.NavigateUrl = string.Format("~/Handlers/FileHandler.ashx?file={0}\n" , file);
            }
        }
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.Buffer = true;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + context.Request.QueryString["files"]);
            context.Response.WriteFile(context.Request.QueryString["files"]);
            context.Response.End();
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the URL has a querystring called "files"??

Comment: @GrantWinney isn't context.Request.QueryString["files"] == string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp")?

Comment: @GrantWinney I see, i thought that it would have links. So how should i do about the files?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Request.QueryString(files)` instead

Comment: Just a comment to let you know that your answer ended up in the "Very Low Quality" review queue, because of how short it is.   I've marked it as "OK", because I can see that it actually answers the question, but to avoid this you might want to be a little less terse.  Cheers.

Comment: Can you add a little explainasion to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

May be a typo, but your code in ItemDataBound is

```
 hyp.NavigateUrl = string.Format("~/Handlers/FileHandler.ashx?file={0}\n" , file);
```

Here you are setting a querystring parameter 'file'

In your handler, ProcessRequest method you are accessing 'files' parameter

```
 context.Response.WriteFile(context.Request.QueryString["files"]);
```

Try changing this to

```
 context.Response.WriteFile(context.Request.Params["file"]);
```

Comment: I have changed that to file but still it doesn't work :/

Comment: @ArielSeah, Try context.Request.Params instead of QueryString